# Convert HTML to PDF using PrimceFaces 7.0 (or higher) Text Editor and Quill

Tags: primefaces, itext, pdf-generation, apache-fop, quill

I use PirmeFaces 7.0 and want to be able to convert the HTML generated by the PrimeFaces TextEditor component

https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/texteditor

into PDF using a Java library, such as itext or apache-fop

Since the above TextEditor component is based on Quill and uses stylesheets from Quill I would like to ask if somebody has experience generating high-quality PDFs based on its input.

Any experience / examples / feedback will be appreciated

**NOTE: In the comments some of you suggest an answer with itext converting from HTML with styles.**

**This does not help me, because** I tried to extract the css file used in the PrimeFaces TextEditor component. And, yes, I extarct it, but... somehow the browser does not recognize it. I do not know why, the file is deliberately made human-unreadable

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, it shows me how to use iText to convert HTMLs (thank you), but no, it does not share any experience as of its ability to use the tools above. But thank you for your reploy!

Comment: That's basic stuff. HTML is value bound to your bean and the CSS is fixed (https://github.com/quilljs/quill/tree/develop/docs/assets/css).

Comment: Look at xhtmlrenderer

Comment: Then download the source of quill. The css is readable there

Comment: @Kukeltje I tried this, bit it does work, Do you know why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61883696/the-quill-publicly-available-css

Comment: You mean it does not work?  Check my comment and investigate...

Comment: @Kukeltje if you mean the link on github  here https://github.com/quilljs/quill/tree/develop/docs/assets/css  there are two css files there. The one that contains my class is this one  https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/develop/docs/assets/css/styles.css but again it is, for my purposes, wrong. The CSS class I am interested in is called ql-size-large. Well, the class is indeed in the second css file, but... preceded by id identificator like this: #demo-container .ql-size-large . This DOES NOT solve my problem, sorry

Comment: No I mean my comment on the other question. Investigate running the js fiddle...

Comment: @Kukeltje Please see the last comment of  deceze in my other question. Anyway I posted two quesitons and I do not know what the problem is. I ve got minuses, but no answers I could undrestand, sorry!